# How can I catch the gestures over UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UICollectionView` and a custom `UICollectionViewCell`

I want to be able to catch the `UICollectionView` gestures as a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, actually I want to handle some gestures collisions by using this delegate's method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

How can I catch the `UICollectionView`'s `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UICollectionView` does listen for taps but not by using a `UIGestureRecognizer`.

But you could add your own `UIGestureRecognizer` for the type your interested in (like `UITapGestureRecognizer` for instance) to the `UICollectionView`, set the delegate on it and in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` return YES or NO depending on whether you want the `UICollectionView` to do it's thing or not, i.e. returning NO would cancel your gesture and allow the collection view to handle the touches.

Or set `delayTouchesBegan` to YES if you just want your gestures to take priority over the collection view touch handling.

More info is here [Collection View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/IncorporatingGestureSupport/IncorporatingGestureSupport.html)